# Equivalent of SQL Server's CONTAINSTABLE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, containstable

I am  converting a Query from SQL Server to MySQL but I have a problem converting the sentence contains table , because it uses `rank` .

I´ve looked for a similar property but I didn´t find anything , here is my Query at SqlServer

```
SELECT KEY_TBL.RANK  
FROM CATS  
INNER JOIN  containsTABLE (CATS,(COLOR,CITY),'ORANGE',1000) AS KEY_TBL ON RUP.ID = KEY_TBL.[KEY]
ORDER BY RANK
```

Comment: I don't know how close it is, but you should look at MySQL full-text indexes and the `MATCH` operator.

Comment: please make a [mre] from your sql server query, somethings aren't straight forward, so an exampple and mysql server version are vital information

Comment: In my experience, SQL Server's `RANK` is a terrible measure of _relevance_ - I get far, far better results with a dedicated search-engine like Lucene, running side-by-side with the canon application database. Just an idea.

Comment: [Microsoft's article on `RANK` goes into surprising detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/limit-search-results-with-rank) and explains that it's based on [Jaccard similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) - but that simple word frequency and proximity weighs a lot more than more advanced analysis. Additionally, SQL Server doesn't really give you many controls for `RANK` besides the `ISABOUT` parameter. YMMV.